# How to add multiple terminal panes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to add integrated terminal panes at multiple places in vscode.
I currently use the terminal-tab in the bottom-panel and I know that one can add terminals in the editor-area.

What I would want to have is

- add terminals as draggable panes in the sidebars
- (optional) add terminal tabs to the bottom panel (see screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can put individual terminals into sections of the sidebars. You can put the whole terminal panel there, but not individual ones. Nor can you drag individual terminals into their own panel tab.

If you really want this, consider raising a feature-request issue ticket.